# Safe base resistor for TIP120

Tags: arduino, transistors, power-electronics

For battery powered application I would like to control power of GSM module and GPS electrically with a TIP120 because GSM can be up to 2A (max_Ic current) and min < 10mA.

[image]

So I would like to know what is the best value of base resistor and the calculation because i learn the electronics by myself. I see on internet the value of 1K, this value can be allow > 500mA for collector emitter ?

My Arduino can be up to 25mA and VCC about 3.4-4.2V ( depend on battery voltage ).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well from datasheet Ib = Ic/250 = 2A/250 = 8mA and Rb = (3.3V - 1.6V)/8mA = 220R.   But you do not have any IRLZ44n?

Comment: @G36 If i use IRFZ44N I will be able to switch my gsm module from the same battery ? can you explain me please ?

Comment: No, you cannot use IR**F**Z44N  you need a Logic Lever MOSFET, for examples: IR**L**Z44N. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @G36 I just see the IRLZ44N datasheet. can I  control directy the gate VGS(th) from the gpio 3.3v trough a voltage divider to allow only 2v from gpio to control the gate ? the difference from the gate voltage and source voltage is 1.3 ( 3.3-2 ) this can work ? This mosfet has low rds(on) my gsm module will have about 3.3 when transistor is on ?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, for the following reasons:

- I suppose your GSM module is connected to a microcontroller, which is not powered off. If you switch your module's GROUND and leave the rest of the IOs connected, then it will be powered through its IOs, and either not work, or die.
- Your transistor is a darlington with high Vce-sat, something like 2V or more. Therefore there will only be 1.3V left on the 3V3 supply and the module won't work.

You need to use a suitable high-side switch. Either an integrated one, or a suitable PMOS.

- [Digikey search with proper criteria already set](http://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-power-distribution-switches-load-drivers/726?FV=ffe002d6%2C1c0002%2C1c0003%2C1c0006%2C3a80035%2C3fc007b%2C3fc007c%2C3fc00c5%2C1180008f%2C118000a4%2C118000ae%2C118000b3%2C11800736%2C118000c8%2C118000d1%2C118000db%2C1180090f%2C118000e8%2C11800981%2C11800982%2C11800983%2C118009b2%2C118009e4%2C11800100%2C11800a0b%2C11800125%2C11800126%2C1180013b%2C11800176%2C11800187%2C1180018d%2C118001a9%2C118001aa%2C1180002b%2C1180002f%2C11800204%2C11800218%2C11800219%2C1180021f%2C11800230%2C11800243%2C1180003a%2C1180024d%2C1180003d%2C1180027d%2C11800286%2C1180004a%2C1180004f%2C11800362%2C11800365%2C1f140000&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250)
- [Example chip](http://www.vishay.com/docs/62754/sip32508.pdf)

Comment: Oh thanks. I don't think about vce sat. Exist a transistor with low vce sat can handle up to 1A in my voltage range? What is the cheap solution ? Thanks

Comment: You should switch the power supply, not the GND. Use a PMOS or a load switch.

Comment: I find this product "PFET Load Switch" http://www.ti.com/product/TPS27082L/datasheet you think is adapted to my circuit ?

Comment: I think it shoudl work.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum current gun for TIP120 is 1000 (http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/TIP120-890130.pdf).
For collector current 2A min base current must be more as 2mA.
Base current if the resistor is 1kOhm is 3.4V/ 1kOhm =3.4mA.
It should also be noted Ube (approximately 1.2 V).
Then (3.4V-1.2V)/1KOhm = 2.2mA.

But MOSFET better than Darlington in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately active region hFE your are talking about has little to do with operating darlington in "saturation" as required by kiki67100. As @G36's written  a few hundred is much realistic. More darlington internal "second" BJT cannot be saturated at all, 2V to 4V Vce(sat) drop should be expected. In short: it's not MOS to be better in this case, they are the ONLY viable option, any darlington is totally useless in a 4V powered design.