# Battery powered application High Side switch

Tags: arduino, batteries, low-power

I want powered GSM module from lithium battery and i want switch off from gpio Arduino to sleep power.

My VCC is 3.2-4.2V is used to powered my Arduino and GSM module. But how can I use n-channel mofset or IC to switch on/off the GSM module from gpio Arduino ?

I think about tip120 but after the voltage drop i don't have enough voltage for my GSM module.

I would like to know if exists a IC or transistor to use the same vcc for Vin and Vout , control by gpio 3.2-4.2V ?

Previous answer : [Safe base resistor for TIP120](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291888/safe-base-resistor-for-tip120)

Sorry for my english i'm french
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you search for load switches, such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps27081a.pdf).  Having a FET as the pass element, the voltage drop will be very low.  This one is capable of 3A with only about 32mOhm Rdson, and simple logic on/off input.

EDIT: I just looked at the link to the other question and noticed you listed the exact same load switch I linked above.  So what was wrong with that?

Comment: I would like to know if exists another way to do that , sorry for duplicate.

Comment: Essentially most high-side load switches are P-ch MOSFETs, so you could make your own from discrete components.  These integrated load switches just make things a little easier for you and the cost is still quite low.

Comment: You asked in the question about using an N-ch MOSFET.  Do you have some issue with using a P-ch FET?  Using a high side switch (i.e. a P-ch FET) allows you to keep the GSM module ground referenced to the Arduino. If you don't use a integrated load switch and 'roll-your-own', you would need a P-ch pass element (MOSFET), and then a N-ch FET or NPN to turn on the P-ch FET.

Comment: Thanks for your additional detail i think i will use integrated circuit. Have a Nice day

Comment: @kiki67100, if AneloQ helped you, please consider accepting or upvoting the answer.

Comment: I have not 15 réputations :-(

Comment: Do you know a IC can be solder by hand ?